# How can I fix error multiple colors of BarChart in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, bar-chart

I have a bar chart to show item using Chart library. I got an error that the explain description show multiple colors for each item. Please help me how can i fix this, i want to show exactly the color like column (only one color), not multiple like this. Thanks for your helping.

[My Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsqg0.png)

Here is my code, note that `items` is dynamic, i got from API:

```
func setDataCount(items: [Item]) {
    let dataEntry = (0..<items.count).map { (i) -> ChartDataEntry in
        let value = Double(items[i].soldQuantity)
        return BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: value)
    }
    
    var arrayDataSet = [IChartDataSet]()
    var arrayColor = [UIColor]()
    
    var set = BarChartDataSet()
    
    for i in 0...items.count - 1 {
        set = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntry, label: items[i].name)
        arrayColor.append(UIColor.random)
        set.colors = arrayColor
        // CONVERT DOUBLE -> INT
        set.valueFormatter = DefaultValueFormatter(decimals: 0)
        arrayDataSet.append(set)
    }
    
    let data = BarChartData(dataSets: arrayDataSet)
    data.setValueFont(.systemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .bold))
    data.barWidth = 0.2

    chartView.data = data
}
```

Comment: `set.colors = [UIColor.random]` instead, and remove `var set = BarChartDataSet()`, it's useless. Just write `var set = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntry, label: items[i].name)`, and remove also `var arrayColor = [UIColor]()`.

Comment: i updated my code like your recommend, the error was resolve but another error comes, three column have the same color, please help me how can fix it

Comment: I think the library requires 3 different colors but UIColor.random for some reason returned the same color on more than one occasion so you might need to make sure the color is not already existing you your arrayColor array before adding it.